# Express Controller Mongoose Query for Ember-Data expected format

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, mongoose, ember-data

I am trying to format json in Ember-Data's expected format using Express/Mongoose on the backend. The payload needs to be in this format:

```
{
  "posts": [{
    "id": 1,
    "user_id": 162,
    "short_desc": "sdfdsfsf",
    "comments_ids": [1, 2]
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "user_id": 162,
    "short_desc": "xcvcxvcxv",
    "comments_ids": [3, 4]
  }],
  "comments": [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "lorem ipsum",
    "body": "lorem ipsum"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "lorem ipsum",
    "body": "lorem ipsum"
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "lorem ipsum",
    "body": "lorem ipsum"
  }, {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "lorem ipsum",
    "body": "lorem ipsum"
  }]
}
```

The Mongoose models are set up as such:

```
var PostSchema = new Schema({
  metadata : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }],
  user_id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },  
  createdAt  : {type : Date}
})

var CommentSchema = new Schema({
  _creator : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post' },
  name: {type : String},
  body: {type : String}
})
```

Here is my basic Express controller. What would be a best practice or a way to handle the scoping of the queries so that I could push each child comment into comments to achieve the right payload format for Ember-data.

```
exports.index = function(req, res){

  comments = [];

  Post
    .find({"user_id": 162},function (err, posts) {
      if (err) throw err;

      posts.forEach(function(post){

        Comments.find({"_creator": post._id},function (err, comments) {

          comments.forEach(function(comment){
            console.log("forEach comment: " + comment);
            comments.push(comment);
          })

        });

      })

      var payload = {"posts": posts, "comments": comments} // comments is empty
      return res.send(200, JSON.stringify(payload));
    })
}
```

I've tried creating closures inside of my forEach logic, but cant seem to push the comment into the comments array in the outer scope. Im sure I'm missing something basic here.

Comment: Moving onto the Mongoose Promise API.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was using a promise, .map(), and the mongoDB $in clause. Together, this cleans up this implementation quite a bit. I glossed over both Promise and $in in the Mongoose API docs.

```
exports.index = function(req, res){

  var promise = Post.find({"user_id": 162}).exec();

      promise
        .then(function(posts){

            var ids = posts.map(function (p) {
              return p._id;
            });

            Comment
              .find({
                '_creator': {
                  $in: ids
                }
              }, function(err, comments) {
                console.log(comments);

                var payload = {"posts": posts, "comments": comments}
                return res.send(200, JSON.stringify(payload));

              });

        })

}
```

Comment: Can I ask you why do you use promise? instead of native callback flow
Thanks

Comment: can u have a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29766025/ember-js-association-access-backend-nodejs-mongoose